# Why Response and JSON tab is different in firebug

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets, gson

My Servlet

```
public class JSONServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static Gson gson = new Gson();
public void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      res.setContentType("application/json");
      res.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(returnVal));
   }
}
```

My Login Function

```
login.login=function(parm0){
$.post(login.url,
   {
     operation:'login',
     userID: 'admin',
     parmData0: JSON.stringify(parm0),
     parmType0: 'com.company.share.svc.login.data.LoginData'
   },
   function(data){
    loginHandler(data);
   },
   'json');
}
```

How I call my login function 
`login.login({userID: 'admin', password: 'admin', forceOut: true});`

This is result in firebug Response tab

```
{"adminUserKey":{"userID":"admin"},"resultCode":0,"sessionID":3788474425691603010,"accountInfoData":[],"userID":"admin","successful":true}
```

And this is result in JSON tab in firebug

```
accountInfoData []
adminUserKey    Object { userID="admin"}
resultCode  0
sessionID 3788474425691603000
successful  true
userID   "admin"
```

As you see sessionIDs are different in two tab. In every login.login(...) method call I get a new session ID.

```
function(data){
   //But in callback method
   //data.sessionID is always 3788474425691603000
   //and never changes.
   //But sessionID in firebug Response tab changes
   //ever login.login(...) call and it is true one
}
```

What am I doing wrong. Why am I getting same sessionID all time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses Doubles (64-bit floats) internally to represent numeric values, so large numbers have limited precision and rounding occurs. I've hit this problem with AJAX/JSON-stuff, the solution is to send the session-id as a string instead of a number ("sessionID":3788474425691603010 vs. "sessionID":"3788474425691603010")